# How to run go-cloud-debug-agent in Google Cloud Run so that I can debug my go app in Stackdriver Debug

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to run go-cloud-debug-agent within Cloud Run

```
FROM golang:1.13.1 
RUN go get -u cloud.google.com/go/cmd/go-cloud-debug-agent
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/xyz
WORKDIR /go/src/xyz
COPY . .

RUN go build -gcflags=all='-N -l' -o main .


EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["go-cloud-debug-agent","-projectid=someproject-12313423","-appmodule=main","-appversion=1.0","--","/go/src/xyz/main"]
```

Unfortunately when trying to deploy it to Cloud Run I see following error in the Stackdriver Logging

```
Error loading program: AttrStmtList not present or not int64 for unit 98
```

Anyone has any clue how to use go-cloud-debug-agent with Cloud Run?

Comment: I have not seen this error, but the debugger is complaining about the program. This error is related to the executable file format (ELF) of the program `main` that you are debugging. Try running your container locally in Docker. Try using version 1.11 to be compatible with the debug agent (the versions must match) but I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley you were right, changing golang to 1.11 resolved the problem, the app is starting using go-cloud-debug-agent.

Comment: Ok it seems go-cloud-debug-agent works but now when I set up the snapshot at any point of app the cloud run is not responding and in Stackdriver Debug I'm waiting forever for snapshot seeing only Waiting for snapshot to hit... Any ideas?

Comment: @MaciejPerliński did you ever fix your "responsiveness" problem?

Comment: @ahong nope i dropped the idea to use this approach but it might be worth revisiting the status now

Answer (score 1):

Go is not supported for Cloud Run at the moment. Here is a list of the supported languages and platforms for Debugger: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/

Comment: As official documentation states there is no official support but having "VMs and Containers running elsewhere" listed in the chart implies we should be able to run the app using Cloud Run (this is docker container) as we would do in VM and still use the debugger agent. Not seeing really a difference between containerized app with debug agent and regular VM. If you are aware what's the difference and why it would not work in Cloud Run please share your thoughts.

Comment: Cloud Run is a Google managed service. VMs and containers running elsewhere are not Google managed services.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnHanley pointed I had to change the golang version to 1.11 to be compatibile with debug agent. 
To conclude the following Dockerfile should run in Cloud Run any golang code and let you use Stackdriver Debug with it.

```
FROM golang:1.11
RUN go get -u cloud.google.com/go/cmd/go-cloud-debug-agent
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/xyz
WORKDIR /go/src/xyz
COPY . .

RUN go build -gcflags=all='-N -l' -o main .


EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["go-cloud-debug-agent","-projectid=someproject-12313423","-appmodule=main","-appversion=1.0","--","/go/src/xyz/main"]
```

GCP should post some examples as from their current documentation I can deduct there is no way to run go-cloud-debug-agent on Cloud Run and that Cloud Run is not supported.